# How to read from all XML files in directory and then combine the info into data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xml-parsing

I wonder how can I do this code, but with multiply files coming from one directory:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('C:/Users/STJ2TW/Desktop/Pliki XML/0204N01323-00_2021082310500900')
root = tree.getroot()

for Type in root.iter('Type'):
    PN = Type.get('name')
    print(f"Part number: {PN}")

for Component in root.iter('Component'):
    CName = Component.get('name')
    if CName == 'Pos010_GearHousing':
         for ComponentNo in Component.iter('ComponentNo'):
            GH = ComponentNo.get('name')
            print(f"Gear Housing: {GH}")

    if CName == 'Pos058_PowerPack':
         for ComponentNo in Component.iter('ComponentNo'):
            PP = ComponentNo.get('name')
            print(f"Power Pack: {PP}")


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Part number:": [PN],
        "Gear Housing:": [GH],
        "Power Pack:": [PP],
    }
)
df

df = df.set_index('Part number:', drop = True)
df.to_csv("C:/Users/STJ2TW/Desktop/Pliki XML/plik.csv", sep=";")
df.head(10)
```

I think I should go with this:

```
path = 'C:/Users/STJ2TW/Desktop/Pliki XML/'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    tree = ET.parse(fullname)
```

But I don't know how to operate on files in the rest of the code. Some loops might be helpful?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this code wouldn't work on 1 file either.

Comment: Do all the XML files have a similar structure? i.e., do they all have 'Part Number', 'Gear Housing' and ' Power Pack'? In other words is this a consolidation exercise?

Comment: can you provide an example of what one of the xml files looks like?

Comment: Yes, all the XML files have a similar structure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you!

Me and my colleague created a function:

```py
def get_data_from_xml(path):
    
    tree = ET.parse(path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    
    for Type in root.iter('Type'):
        PN = Type.get('name')

        for Component in root.iter('Component'):
            CName = Component.get('name')
            if CName == 'Pos010_GearHousing':
                 for ComponentNo in Component.iter('ComponentNo'):
                    GH = ComponentNo.get('name')                   

            if CName == 'Pos058_PowerPack':
                 for ComponentNo in Component.iter('ComponentNo'):
                    PP = ComponentNo.get('name')

    return PN, GH, PP
```

and then created lists:

```
pn_list = []
gh_list = []
pp_list = []
```

Used the function:

```
path = 'C:/Users/STJ2TW/Desktop/Pliki XML/'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    PN, GH, PP = get_data_from_xml(fullname)
    pn_list.append(PN)
    gh_list.append(GH)
    pp_list.append(PP)
```

And put it all to the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Part number': pn_list,
     'Gear Housing': gh_list,
     'Power Pack': pp_list
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.  It's hard to say for sure without knowing the structure of the xml file, but based on the code you provided it seems like this might work.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os


path = 'C:/Users/STJ2TW/Desktop/Pliki XML/'
master = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    tree = ET.parse(fullname)
    root = tree.getroot()
    items = []   # collect items into a list of dictionaries

    for Type in root.iter('Type'):
        PN = Type.get('name')
        items.append({"Part Number": PN})   # add data to dictionary
        print(f"Part number: {PN}")

    for i, Component in enumerate(root.iter('Component')):
        CName = Component.get('name')
        if CName == 'Pos010_GearHousing':
            for ComponentNo in Component.iter('ComponentNo'):
                GH = ComponentNo.get('name')
                items[i]["Gear Housing"] = GH  # update dictionary
                print(f"Gear Housing: {GH}")


        if CName == 'Pos058_PowerPack':
            for ComponentNo in Component.iter('ComponentNo'):
                PP = ComponentNo.get('name')
                items[i]["Power Pack"] = PP  # update dictionary
                print(f"Power Pack: {PP}")
    master += items  # add dictionary list for this file to the 
                     # master list for all files


df = pd.DataFrame(master)  # Create dataframe from master list
df = df.set_index('Part Number', drop = True)
df.to_csv("C:/Users/STJ2TW/Desktop/Pliki XML/plik.csv", sep=";")
df.head(10)
```

Comment: The *for ComponentNo...* loops won't work because *items[i]["Gear Housing"]* will be continually reassigned and thus only be equal to the last GH/PP observed in the loop. Also, how do you guarantee to correlate part numbers with their associated Gear Housing and Power Pack?

Comment: i see what you are saying...  I am guessing based on the OPs code there is exactly one Power pack, and/or Gear house for each product number.... without the structure of the xml I can't really get any more precise than that.  Regardless the question was how to create a dataframe from multiple xml files in the same directory and this does demonstrate how to do that at least

Comment: @OldBill  I can't guarantee anything without knowing the structure of the xml file.  I am just making educated guesses based on the code already provided by the OP